# How to transition from Blueprint to C++ in Unreal Engine 5.0.1?

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I am new in Unreal Engine. And I am trying to edit a UE project, but it's using blueprint for the coding, and I have none experience for using blueprint.

So is it possible and how to change Blueprint Class into C++ in UE?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can transition from Blueprint to C++ in Unreal Engine. Here is the step

Create a C++ Class In Unreal Engine, you'll need to create a new C++ class based on the functionality you want to implement.

Open the newly created C++ class and define all member variables, functions, and override relevant Unreal Engine functions to replicate the logic from your Blueprint.

After you done the code. go back to Unreal Engine and compile the project by clicking on the "Compile" button. Done